Force float value when using JSON
I'm encountering an issue where my backend sends JSON data containing float numbers (e.g., 10.0, 20.0) to the UI side. However, upon receiving these numbers in the UI and logging them to the console, I observe that they are automatically converted to integers (10 and 20) instead of retaining their original float format. Strangely, numbers with a fractional part (e.g., 20.1) remain unchanged as 20.1.
I found the solution that I want. This is taken from stringify-with-floats npm library but modified to support any length of floats.


const stringifyWithFloats = (config = {}, decimals = 1) => {
  const beginFloat = '__FLOAT__BEGIN__';
  const endFloat = '__FLOAT__END__';

  return (inputValue, inputReplacer, space) => {
    const inputReplacerIsFunction = typeof inputReplacer === "function";
    let isFirstIteration = true;

    const jsonReplacer = (key, val) => {
      if (isFirstIteration) {
        isFirstIteration = false;
        return inputReplacerIsFunction ? inputReplacer(key, val) : val;
      }

      let value;
      if (inputReplacerIsFunction) {
        value = inputReplacer(key, val);
      } else if (Array.isArray(inputReplacer)) {
        value = inputReplacer.indexOf(key) !== -1 ? val : undefined;
      } else {
        value = val;
      }

      const forceFloat =
        config[key] === "float" &&
        (value || value === 0) &&
        typeof value === "number" &&
        !value.toString().toLowerCase().includes("e");

      return forceFloat ? `${beginFloat}${value}${endFloat}` : value;
    };

    const json = JSON.stringify(inputValue, jsonReplacer, space);

    const regexReplacer = (match, num) => {
      return num.includes(".") || Number.isNaN(num)
        ? Number.isNaN(num)
          ? num
          : Number(num).toFixed(decimals)
        : `${num}.${"0".repeat(decimals)}`;
    };

    const re = new RegExp(`"${beginFloat}(.+?)${endFloat}"`, "g");
    return json.replace(re, regexReplacer);
  };
};

// Test input
const testInput = {
  foo: 10.0,
  bar: {
    baz: 20.0,
    qux: {
      value: 30.0
    }
  }
};

// Configure the stringifyWithFloats function
const customStringify = stringifyWithFloats({ foo: 'float', 'bar.baz': 'float' });

// Serialize the test input
const serializedJson = customStringify(testInput, null, 2);

// Output the serialized JSON
console.log(serializedJson);



Output:
{
  "foo": 10.0,
  "bar": {
    "baz": 20,
    "qux": {
      "value": 30
    }
  }

}
So now the main issue and question. How to make this regex magic to handle nested objects and processes numbers as floats where required. AS you can see "foo" is shown correctly 10.0, but baz and value are not

Numbers don't have a format. They only contain their numeric value: 20.0 == 20 == 20.0000. If you want to store a format, you have to use strings or a different data type.

You will need to format the numbers to add in the decimal when they are being displayed.  See Number.toFixed

@James toFixed gives me "10.0" but i want to retain it as number

Main issue that backend sent me data with floating numbers and i am returning number without floating. So basically it has incorrect data. But i need all decimals to show it in display monitors

As noted, 10.0 is exactly the same value as 10. What you're noticing is the normal way JavaScript takes a number value and makes it presentable for output by converting it to a string. You can use number formatting facilities to format numbers however you like.

Also the word "floating" does not mean what you think it means. In "10.0", the ".0" is the fractional part of the value. Specifically, it means "0/10", which is zero. So 10 plus 0 is 10. That's why 10.0 and 10 are the same. All JavaScript numbers (well except bigint) are floating-point numbers, even if when shown in output they look like integers.

@Pointy I understand the issue. Even after making changes to received data, when I send it back to the backend, the numbers are being converted to integers (e.g., 10, 20) instead of remaining in their original float format (e.g., 10.0, 20.0). However, I need to preserve the original format (10.0, 20.0) when storing data on the backend.

Well that sounds like a problem for your back-end code. Again, JavaScript numbers are floating-point numbers, and numbers don't carry around a format. If you want to send formatted numbers with zeros after the decimal point, format them yourself. Everything is a string when sent via HTTP anyway.

In addition, that's not a JavaScript thing. All programming languages I know behave like this. The numbers are not converted to integers. The only integer type in JavaScript is BigInt.

@jabaa I found the similar result what i want and edited question

No, you have the same issue. JSON stands for "Java Script Object Notation" and is a standard for producing strings used for serial information interchange. If you define the value of, say, qux as 42.00 instead of 42 in the JSON string, parsing the value using JSON.parse on the front end will still convert it back to a number data type with value 42: which mathematically belongs to both I (the set of integers) and R (the set of reals). If you want to produced video output of the number with fixed precision on the front end it needs to be formatted (on the front end).

I can't close the question because I retracted a close vote after you edited the question. The duplicate previously suggested was this question which I now agree with, albeit for the second time.

In JSON there is only one number type integer fraction exponent. It's always a floating point number, even when the fraction and exponent are missing.

The latest edit is still showing how you've modified the JSON string. JSON.parse does not care.

I made a monster which gives me desired reuslt.This code provides a flexible way to serialize JavaScript objects into JSON strings while selectively formatting numeric values as floats based on a configurable set of rules (config). It handles nested objects recursively and ensures that numeric values are properly formatted using regular expressions after serialization.


const stringifyWithFloats = (config = {}, decimals = 1) => {
  const beginFloat = '__FLOAT__BEGIN__';
  const endFloat = '__FLOAT__END__';

  return (inputValue, inputReplacer, space) => {
const inputReplacerIsFunction = typeof inputReplacer === 'function';

const jsonReplacer = (key, val, path) => {
  const currentPath = path.concat(key).join('.');
  let value;
  if (inputReplacerIsFunction) {
    value = inputReplacer(key, val);
  } else if (Array.isArray(inputReplacer)) {
    value = inputReplacer.indexOf(key) !== -1 ? val : undefined;
  } else {
    value = val;
  }

  const forceFloat =
    (config[currentPath] === 'float' || config[key] === 'float') &&
    (value || value === 0) &&
    typeof value === 'number' &&
    !value.toString().toLowerCase().includes('e');

  return forceFloat ? `${beginFloat}${value}${endFloat}` : value;
};

const deepJsonReplacer = (obj, path = []) => {
  if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
      (acc, k) => {
        acc[k] = deepJsonReplacer(obj[k], path.concat(k));
        return acc;
      },
      Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {}
    );
  } else {
    return jsonReplacer(path[path.length - 1], obj, path.slice(0, -1));
  }
};

const json = JSON.stringify(deepJsonReplacer(inputValue), null, space);

const regexReplacer = (match, num) => {
  return num.includes('.') || Number.isNaN(num)
    ? Number.isNaN(num)
      ? num
      : Number(num).toFixed(decimals)
    : `${num}.${'0'.repeat(decimals)}`;
};

const re = new RegExp(`"${beginFloat}(.+?)${endFloat}"`, 'g');
return json.replace(re, regexReplacer);
  };
};

const generateFloatConfig = (obj, basePath = '') => {
  let config = {};

  for (let key in obj) {
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  let newBasePath = basePath ? `${basePath}.${key}` : key;

  if (
    typeof obj[key] === 'object' &&
    obj[key] !== null &&
    !Array.isArray(obj[key])
  ) {
    Object.assign(config, generateFloatConfig(obj[key], newBasePath));
  } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'number') {
    config[newBasePath] = 'float';
  }
}
  }

  return config;
};

const testInput = {
  foo: 10.0,
  bar: {
baz: 20.0,
qux: {
  value: 30.0
}
  }
};

const floatConfig = generateFloatConfig(testInput);
const customStringify = stringifyWithFloats(floatConfig);
const serializedJson = customStringify(testInput, null, 2);

console.log(serializedJson);




Keep in mind, that every JSON library that parses this string, is allowed to ignore the decimal part. TBH, I don't know a library in any programming language that would handle 10.0 differently than 10. Do you have an example? Also keep in mind that you get the same output for testinput 10, 10.0 and 10.0000. It doesn't store the number format. It formats the output in a fixed way. This code converts "integers" to "floats".

Thanks @jabaa I understood. Generally, I am working with displays and monitors in medicine and I want to show the temperature as 10.0 C to 25.5 for example. But it always converts to 10 to 25.5.

You're mixing responsibilities. The UI is responsible for the format. It should format the number to fixed decimals. The data has the value 10. The format is not part of the data. Formatting should happen as the last step in processing, not at the beginning. This code doesn't retain the original float format as asked in the question.

Downvoted because this answer doesn't address the problem of how to present numbers with no fractional part or with insufficient significant trailing decimal digits to make up some required number of decimal digits after the decimal point on a display driven by front end software. It does show advances made in server code to pad out the JSON decimal encoded value of a number, with trailing zeros after the decimal point which, because they don't alter the number value encoded before such padding was performed, will be ignored by JSON.parse anyway.
