How to retain two decimal places in numbers
There is a front-end
payload: {
    a: '1.00'
}

Then I converted it: Number (parseFloat (payload. a). toFixed (2)), and the result was payload. a=1, not 1.00 for the number type
i need 
    1.00 => 1.00
    1.01 => 1.01
    1.011 => 1.01
    1.10 => 1.10
all number


Not possible. That's not how numbers work. If you want a specific representation of a number, you need to use a string.

Simple rules: Use numbers while storing and calculating. Format numbers on output.

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78711363/force-float-value-when-using-json

@Wiimm Thank you for your reply. The data that the backend needs to store now is 1.00 of type number, but in reality, what I have obtained is 1
